# My broadleafcommerce admin view have less features that what is in the live demo

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am using broadleaf commerce 6.1.3. My admin panel seems to have less features than what is in the demo as shown. What could be the reason?-

[image: my panel]
[image: demo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the free Community version, while the demo is for the paid Enterprise version.

Comment: Thank you very much @mouse_8b